# post to tumblr using php

Tags: php, tumblr

Could anyone help me figure out how to post to tumblr using php.
I tried googling for a library or a sample code but couldn't find one. all I can find is this here https://github.com/alexdunae/tumblr-php/blob/master/Tumblr.php and it doesnt seem to work also I looked and tried the code on v1 api at tumblr website that doesnt work either ....

```
 function post($data){
                if(function_exists("curl_version")){
                        $data["email"] = $this->email;
                        $data["password"] = $this->password;
                        $data["generator"] = $this->generator;
                        $request = http_build_query($data);
                        $c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
                        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POST,true);
                        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request);
                        curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                        $return = curl_exec($c);
                        $status = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                        curl_close($c);
                        if($status == "201"){
                            return true;
                        }
                        elseif($status == "403"){
                            return false;
                        }
                        else{
                            return "error: $return";
                        }
                }
                else{
                        return "error: cURL not installed";
                }
        }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: **ALWAYS** read the **official documentation**, normally located at the **official website**, http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that this is showing up as Featured for Tumblr and I want to say this: As of 2012, you should IGNORE the above answer by Tuga because it DOES NOT work with the newest Tumblr API.

What you need is [TumblrOAuth](https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth) which is built from [OAuth Sandbox](https://github.com/fangel/oauth-sandbox/blob/master/library/OAuth.php).

It is only setup to read and write Tumblr posts, so if you want to do more than that, you'll need to alter the code. I used it as my code base for [Followr](http://krisallengallery.com/followr/).

Answer (score 1):

Stolen from http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api

```
// Authorization info
$tumblr_email    = 'info@davidville.com';
$tumblr_password = 'secret';

// Data for new record
$post_type  = 'regular';
$post_title = 'The post title';
$post_body  = 'This is the body of the post.';

// Prepare POST request
$request_data = http_build_query(
    array(
        'email'     => $tumblr_email,
        'password'  => $tumblr_password,
        'type'      => $post_type,
        'title'     => $post_title,
        'body'      => $post_body,
        'generator' => 'API example'
    )
);

// Send the POST request (with cURL)
$c = curl_init('http://www.tumblr.com/api/write');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($c);
$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($c);

// Check for success
if ($status == 201) {
    echo "Success! The new post ID is $result.\n";
} else if ($status == 403) {
    echo 'Bad email or password';
} else {
    echo "Error: $result\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work ... tumblr have changed the authentication process to include oauth ... i already tried this .... thanks for the effort and help though, I appreciate ur response

Comment: It seems that thumblr is using API v2 now, I didn't find a script but I managed to find some good documentation, [tumblr api v2 #posting](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting). If you find a solution please post it here for future help, I'll do the same. GL :)

Comment: I've found a [Pyblr](https://github.com/ToQoz/Pyblr), a simple Tumblr API v2 library written in python, see if you manage to work with it, it pretty new (4 August 2011).

Comment: Tumblr has now disabled their old API (v1), so this won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

```
$conskey = "CONSUMER KEY";
$conssec = "CONSUMER SECRET";

$tumblr_blog = "myblog.tumblr.com";
$to_be_posted = "This is the text to be posted";

$oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/".$tumblr_blog."/post", array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>$to_be_posted), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST);

$result = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());

if($result->meta->status == 200){
  echo 'Success!';
}
```

This code will let you post to your tumblr blog using tumblr API.

I hope this code helps.

Comment: How did you try to code it? Can you post it here so we can help.

Comment: you are missing OAuth class.

Comment: You need to make sure that your php version has the OAuth extension enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The api example provided by Tuga is working for me (on Wordpress)...so I think your problem lies elsewhere, and not with the example provided. I would also be very appreciative if you guys got a version 2 api working if you could post it.