# Posting content to Tumblr

Tags: php, tumblr

I have already tried below code,

```
function upload_content(){
    // Authorization info
    $tumblr_email    = 'email-address@host.com';
    $tumblr_password = 'secret';
    // Data for new record
    $post_type  = 'text';
    $post_title = 'Host';
    $post_body  = 'This is the body of the host.';
    // Prepare POST request
    $request_data = http_build_query(
        array(
            'email'     => $tumblr_email,
            'password'  => $tumblr_password,
            'type'      => $post_type,
            'title'     => $post_title,
            'body'      => $post_body,
            'generator' => 'API example'
        )
    );
    // Send the POST request (with cURL)
    $c = curl_init('api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/gurjotsinghmaan.tumblr.com/post');  
    //api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/post       
    //http://www.tumblr.com/api/write       
    //http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts/text?api_key={}
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_data);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($c);
    $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
    // Check for success
    if ($status == 201) {
        echo "Success! The new post ID is $result.\n";
    } else if ($status == 403) {
        echo 'Bad email or password';
    } else {
        echo "Error: $result\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about this code? What errors do you get etc? What happens if you manually submit a request using the cli version of curl to that endpoint?

Comment: i have provided some url suggested,
i get diffrent errors by diff urls. like: bad email or pass word
and invalid credentials etc.

Comment: Please refer to this post [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171750/post-to-tumblr-using-php/12142121#12142121

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the proper Tumblr endpoint:

http://www.tumblr.com/api/write

I'm pretty sure the others won't work.

Obviously make sure that your user and pass are correct, other than that, this looks fine - it's pretty much exactly what I'd write.